# Detecting success/failure with Typescript watcher Compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

The Typescript compiler APIs allow for programmatic creation of watch compilers through the use of the `ts.createWatchCompilerHost` API, with an example of it's use demonstrated in the Typescript docs [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#writing-an-incremental-program-watcher).

This API accepts a callback as its last argument that will be called anytime the watch status changes, with a `Diagnostic` object provided that describes the change in the watch status.

Using these diagnostic events, I'm attempting to discern between a `compiling`, `success`, and `failure` state. I've got detection of `compiling` state working fine, but I've come across an oddity when determining the difference between `success` and `failure`.

The trouble I'm having is due to the fact that the diagnostic codes are applied as follows. If there was 1 error while building, code `6193` is provided, otherwise code `6194` is provided. This means that code `6194` is provided if there were no errors (a `success`) or if there were 2+ errors (a `failure`). You can see this logic in the ts compiler [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1bd631e593c1f3cf3ec0bd8ccba27d67094a158a/src/compiler/watch.ts#L95).

What is the expected way for a user of `createWatchCompilerHost` to determine between the case of no errors on build and the case of 1+ errors on build?

A hacky solution is to parse the `diagnostic.messageText` to check for `Found 0 errors.` but that seems extremely fragile and is a solution I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: It's very strange it has the same diagnostic code for 0 errors and 2+ errors. The code in the compiler doesn't look correct to me, but it's done a few times so maybe it is correct. You may want to open an issue in the typescript repo about this to see what they say.

Comment: In case anyone gets here wondering the same thing, I've opened up an issue against the typescript repo on github: [Issue Link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32542).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TS 3.7**

In TypeScript 3.7 there is now an `errorCount` parameter on `reportWatchStatusChanged`:

```
function reportWatchStatusChanged(
    diagnostic: Diagnostic,
    newLine: string,
    options: CompilerOptions,
    // I'm not sure why this is nullable, I am asking in the issue
    errorCount?: number
) {
    // check error count here
}
```

**Pre-TS 3.7**

Given the following watch host from the example:

```
const host = ts.createWatchCompilerHost(
  configPath,
  {},
  ts.sys,
  createProgram,
  reportDiagnostic,
  reportWatchStatusChanged
);
```

You could add a flag that's triggered by the `reportDiagnostic` callback and then check and reset that flag in `reportWatchStatusChanged`.

For example:

```
let hadDiagnostics = false;

function reportDiagnostic(diagnostic: ts.Diagnostic) {
  hadDiagnostics = true;
  // ...etc...
}

function reportWatchStatusChanged(diagnostic: ts.Diagnostic) {
  if (hadDiagnostics) {
      console.log("Failed.");
      hadDiagnostics = false;
  } else {
      console.log("Success.");
  }

  // ...etc...
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but my only worry was if there was some type of reported `Diagnostic` that didn't actually represent a real error. Is every `Diagnostic` passed to `reportDiagnostic` representing some actual error?

Comment: @casieber yes. I just took a look through the source to confirm and they will all be actual errors (see how `reportDiagnostic` is called [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1bd631e593c1f3cf3ec0bd8ccba27d67094a158a/src/compiler/watch.ts#L133)). As you mentioned in the question though, it would be nice if the diagnostic code were different for a success vs a failure with 2+ errors.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer and check with the TS team about getting something to differentiate.